# How to refer to a specific object of a specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a "foreach" in thymeleaf that generate bootstrap's cards, for each card i added a textarea and a button which you can use to comment; after that i used an AJAX post call to comment, but i'm not able to recognize the specific textarea in the form of the button that has been clicked, and insted my js code works only for the first element(so the first textarea).

!even using the class selector insted of the id selector i get the same error :(

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // SUBMIT FORM
  $('.form-inline').submit(function(event) {
    // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxPost();
  });

  function ajaxPost() {
    // PREPARE FORM DATA
    var formData = {
      description: $('.description-class').val(),
      id: $('.id-class').val()
    }

    // DO POST
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "/api/customer/save/" + formData.id,
      data: JSON.stringify(formData),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.status == "Done") {
          $("#postResultDiv").html("<p style='background-color:#888E90; color:white; padding:20px 20px 20px 20px'>" +
            "Il commento è stato aggiunto correttamente! <br>" +
            "Commento aggiunto = " +
            result.data.description + "<br>" + "Id: " + result.data.id + "</p>");
        } else {
          $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
        }
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        alert("Error!")
        console.log("ERROR: ", e);
      }
    });

    // Reset FormData after Posting
    resetData();

  }

  function resetData() {
    $("#description").val("");
  }
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr th:each="report : ${reports}">

    <form class="form-inline" id="customerForm" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="description-class" id="description" name="description" rows="3" cols="70">Write...</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="id-class" id="id" name="id" rows="3" cols="70" th:text="${report.id}" style="display:none">id</textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" style="height: 25px;">
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="postResultDiv" id="postResultDiv">
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you have more then one form? I maybe do not understand your intend but I think you have to send a form's reference while calling ajaxPost like: ajaxPost( this ); initialize your function like: function ajaxPost( form ) { and get value like this: $( '.description-class', form ).val()

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the id because ids cannot be repeated as these must be unique you must use the class and as class contains multiple items you should use `document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')[textBoxNumber]`

> textBoxNumber could be 1,2,3 any text box no you want to access

And make it sure that you have included the jquery cdn or local before this js code

Comment: i just would like to access the specific form textbox..something like this.textbox ..so it would work for every form

Comment: Did you check my comment on your question?

Comment: Iterate the elements and use (this) like i am explaining here *$('.className').each(function () { $(this).val() })* this will give you the single element